# Python SSLError on Ubuntu, but only when run from a CRON

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron, sni

I have a Python script using requests module. It works on my desktop (Windows), and works when I run it manually on my VM (Ubuntu 14.04 / python 2.7.14).
However, when the exact same command is scheduled as a CRON job on the same VM, it's failing.

The offending line seems to be:

```
index_response = requests.get(my_https_URL, verify=False)
```

The (slightly redacted) response is:

```
(<class 'requests.exceptions.SSLError'>, SSLError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host=my_https_URL, port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:510: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure'),))",),), <traceback object at 0x7f3d877ce5f0>)
```

HTTP URLs don't seem to be affected, and indeed some HTTPS URLs *are* working... (I think it's domains requiring SNI which are not working).

I've tried adding `verify=False`, and even running the CRON script as sudo, but no update.
It originally failed when I was running it manually, but I then installed python2.7.14 (in addition to python 2.7.6), which resolved the manual issue. To add some further complexity, the script is being triggered by another one using `exec` (the test runner runs various tests scripts including this one) - could this be related?

I didn't have this problem in urllib2, but would prefer not to move back from requests to urllib2 if I can help it...

Comment: are both interpreters on your path? maybe cron uses the false one

Comment: @Mandraenke - I think this is it; `python2.7 myscript.py` works, but `python myscript.py` doesn't. I'm totally a Windows person, so I just need to figure out how to update my path; thanks for the tip. So related to my Python installation, and not Python or the sites themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can format here better now as an answer:

If might be that cron simply picks the wrong interpreter in your case. A simple solution is to provide the full path to it, you can find it with:

```
md@gw1:~$ type python2.7
python2.7 is /usr/bin/python2.7
md@gw1:~$
```

Now use inside your crontab:

```
0 12 * * * /usr/bin/python2.7 your_script.py
```

Alternatively use a so called shebang:

```
md@gw1:~$ cat your_script.py
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

print "hello"

md@gw1:~$ chmod +x your_script.py
md@gw1:~$ ./your_script.py
hello
md@gw1:~$
```

The first line in your_script.py and the chmod made it executeble and will use the correct interpreter.

Comment: Brilliant answer - thank you! Incidentally for `$ type python2.7` I got `python2.7 is hashed (/usr/local/bin/python2.7)` - no idea what hashed means in this context, but using that path as recommended worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case service was trying to fetch large json and save it to db.
I've tried to rewrite the code from using node's https module to requests and etc.

But the real reason was as described by @Mandraenke above.
As I've installed nvm - **cron job probably used an incorrect node version**.

So, I've shown the current version with `type node` and in the job replaced

`0 4 * * * node my-script.js` with

`0 4 * * * /home/my-user/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.1/bin/node my-script.js`